# Automating Namecheap's browser DNS update with Java — can anyone give some suggestions to proof-of-concept code?

Tags: java, dns, network-programming, ip-address, fault-tolerance

The domain name registrar Namecheap offers a service where customers can point their domains to their IP addresses simply using the browser.

> How do I use a browser to dynamically update the host's IP?
>
> The Dynamic DNS feature is available only for the domains pointed to our BasicDNS, PremiumDNS or FreeDNS.
>
> Please substitute these with appropriate values for host, domain, password and IP:
>   https://dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/update?host=[host]&domain=[domain_name]&password=[ddns_password]&ip=[your_ip]
>
> Fields that are to be changed in the URL are: [host], [domain_name], [ddns_password] and [your_ip].

Nice feature, but I want to automate it. I came up with this in Java, but I'm not particularly familiar with HTTP protocols in the language and I'm not great at error handling. This won't get me a letter grade above a D any time soon but here's the general plan:

```
package myServerUtils;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class IPPointer {
    public static String IPinitial, Password;
    // Time to wait between checks - decreases as IP changes more frequently, increases as IP changes less frequently
    public static long delay = 21600000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length == 3 & correctAddrFormat(args[0]) & correctNameFormat(args[1])) {
            Thread dynamicdns = new Thread(new pointerDaemon(args [0], args[1], args[2]) );
            dynamicdns.start();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect format - please enter as <IP address> <domain name> <DynamicDNS password>"
                    + "\nExiting...");
        }


    }

    // Should return true for argument in ip format, i.e., 198.0.0.1 splits to length 4
    static boolean correctAddrFormat(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split(".");
        if (parts.length == 4)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }

    // Should return true for argument in domain name format, i.e., example.com splits to length 2
    static boolean correctNameFormat(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split(".");
        if (parts.length == 2)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
}


class pointerDaemon implements Runnable{
    private String currentIP, domain, password, fetchedIP;

    public pointerDaemon(String ip, String domain, String password) {
        this.currentIP = ip;
        this.domain = domain;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
        System.out.println("Attempting to synchronize IP pointer...");
        fetchedIP = getIP();
        if (fetchedIP.equals(currentIP)){
            System.out.println("IP already synchronized.");
            if (IPPointer.delay < 259200000L) {
                IPPointer.delay = Math.round(IPPointer.delay * 1.1);
            }
        }else if(!fetchedIP.equals(currentIP) & !fetchedIP.equals(null)) {
            currentIP = fetchedIP;
            connectToDNS(currentIP, domain, password);
            if (IPPointer.delay > 7200000) {
                IPPointer.delay = Math.round(IPPointer.delay * 0.9);
            }
        }else if(fetchedIP.equals(null)) {
            System.out.println("Bad public IP fetch...");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Don't know what's happening here. Don't much like it...");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(IPPointer.delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Thread has died of insomnia...?");
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    public void connectToDNS(String i, String d, String p) {
        try {
            URL updateService = new URL ("https://dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/update?host=@&domain="+d+"&password="+p+"&ip="+i);
            try {
                URLConnection updateServiceConnection = updateService.openConnection();
                updateServiceConnection.connect();
                System.out.println("Update successful.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException in method connectToDNS...\nReturning without update...");
                return;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception in method connectToDNS...\nReturning without update...");
            return;
        }

    }

    public String getIP () {
        try {
            URL whois = new URL("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com");
            BufferedReader fetcher = 
                     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whois.openStream()));
            String s = fetcher.readLine().trim();
            fetcher.close();
            return s;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception in method getIP...\nReturning null...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in method getIP...\nReturning null...");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Theoretically, this works as is (assuming I didn't forget to escape all the proper special characters and that the URLConnection.connect() method is sufficient to send the request to update), but it's about as fault tolerant as an overripe tomato and developing robust code in Java is not my strong suit. Especially when it comes to networking...

I'd greatly appreciate some suggestions on how to clean this up and ensure reliability — thank you all.

Comment: I would suggest you switch from the built-in `URLConnection` to [Apache HttpComponents HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) to clean your code up *and* then use [Netflix Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) (or [resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j)) to add reliability.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you for the pointer! I'll look into those resources. If you have any code snippets as example I'd love to see them as well. Thank you.